# Spinning wheel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am using following code to show a spinning wheel:

```
$("#loading")
.hide()
.ajaxStart(function(){

    $(this).show();
    setTimeout("3000");
})
.ajaxStop(function(){

    $(this).hide("slow");
})
;
```

and:

```
<div id="loading">
            <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```

Problem:
"setTimeout() is not working. And how can I display the image at the centre of webpage?"

Comment: "`setTimeout()` is not working"... what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The usage of setTimeout is such that you must provide it with a function to execute after the pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why you're using the timer, you can simply turn it on at start of ajax request, and then on success or error turn it off, like:

```
$('#loading').show();

$.post(url, request)

    .success(function(data) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        // Do what you want with data
    })

    .error(function(data) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        // Show error message
    });
```

To have your loading image in the middle of the page, make sure that it's container is within a 100% height parent, and if it is nested, make sure none of its parents are `position:relative`.

```
#loading {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#loading img {
    margin-top: -12px; // Half images height;
    margin-left: -12px; // Half images width;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

OR

#loading {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#loading img {
    width:24px // Images width
    height:auto; // If Image size changes don't mess with proportions
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:48%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` takes 2 paramter, the first one is the `callback`function and the second is the `timeout` in msec
eg.

```
setTimeout(funcname,1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //do stuff
},1000);
```

to display your image in center of the webpage you can use eg. this technique

```
#loading {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:-50px; //negative half of width
    height:80px;
    margin-top:-40px; //negative half of height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#loading {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   top: 48%;
   left: 48%
}
```

JS

```
$('#loading').ajaxStart(function(){
   var that = $(this)
    setTimeout(function() {
       that.show();
    }, "3000");
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide("slow");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the SetTimeout function in a wrong way

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

// do sth

 }, 3000);
```